# Not able to run emulator.exe

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying to run the sms app and I need two instances of emulator on same machine. Eclipse is up and running however, the android-sdk-windows>tools>emulator.exe does not run at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AVD](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) and [emulator](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) documentation explains how to create an AVD and launch an emulator.  You will need one AVD for each instance of the emulator you wish to run.

Comment: Hello Dre, I understand your point, but then how will I run two eumlators at same time? I want to send an sms from one to another

Comment: You would create two AVDs, and launch two instances of the emulator, one using the first AVD, and one using the second AVD

Comment: right click on project folder>run as>run configurations>Target>choose different AVD each time you run.